# SQLServer.exe utilizes almost 95% of the RAM in SharePoint farm based SQL Server

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, performance, space-usage

We have a single Server dedicated for SQL DB in our sharepoint farm. Now I do see the task manager of the DB Server regularly and find day by day the RAM utilization is increasing upto 95% by only sqlserver.exe process. I am worried if that % goes to 100% and the system gets hanged then no request will be served

FYI: the min and max memory configuration settings are set to default. We have not added any additional resources as well.

Request you to guide me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is typical behavior for a SQL server, SQL will take up almost all the available RAM.